# Looking a way to parse anom root in kafka message with Masstrasit

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, masstransit

Creating the the consumer classes is a `List<T>`, and the class would be for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<MyPoco> request { get; set; } 
}
```

The payload we are getting in Kafka is

```
[
   {
      "Attempts":[
         {
            "Answers":[
               
            ]
         }
      ],
      "Property":"text"
   },
   {
      "Attempts":[
         {
            "Answers":[
               
            ]
         }
      ],
      "Property":"text"
   }
]
```

Consumer is set the same way as usual, this message doesn't even hit, is there a way to make the consumers accept anom payloads?

Thanks in advance!